# parse excel data and store as per Map<String, List<>> structure

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have an excel sheet as shown below

```
Date    Amount  Client
13/03/2018  79  0017F00000Ujs3C
13/03/2018  86  0017F00000Ujs3C
13/03/2018  50  0017F00000Ujs3C
```

I need to parse the excel file using apache POI and store data column wise

and store data as per this Map> structure

This is program

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
public class ExcelReader
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
        File myFile = new File("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\test.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);

         Map<String, List<String>> myMaps = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        int numberofsheetspresent = workBook.getNumberOfSheets();
        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberofsheetspresent; i++) {
            String sheetname = workBook.getSheetName(i);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheet(sheetname);
            for (Row eachRow : sheet) {
                //List rowDataList = new LinkedList();
                for (Cell cellData : eachRow) {
                    String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cellData);
                        System.out.println(cellValue);
                }
            }
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

It is reading the data row-wise . could you please help me how to create a 
Map> structure with the above excel

```
String   : List

Date     :  {13/03/2018  , 13/03/2018 , 13/03/2018 }
Amount      :  {79  , 86, 50}
Client     :  {0017F00000Ujs3C , 0017F00000Ujs3C, 0017F00000Ujs3C}
```

Comment: Without knowing what you want your map key to be there's not much we can do to help....

Comment: Map keys to be all column names and its list must be corresponding   row data .

Comment: Grab row one, record the values there as your keys, then process all the other rows fetching cells by index not iterator and store? See http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator

Comment: Thanks for the response , you mean to to hard code ??

Comment: I have tried but its reading as rowwise only and this is the output [[Date, Amount, Client], [13/03/2018, 79, 0017F00000Ujs3C], [13/03/2018, 86, 0017F00000Ujs3C], [13/03/2018, 50, 0017F00000Ujs3C]]

Comment: It may read row-wise, but that doesn't mean you have to store row-wise in your map! Just invert it as you go along